Why won't the Charles Proxy root certificate install into my keychain?
I double click or drag the .pem onto my keychain, and no error message. It just doesn't install into the keychain.

..on my Intel machine. Installs fine on my M1 and M3 machines. Same version of MacOS, the latest upgrade.
